# Get quantity of the active selected product variation in WooCommerce

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce, product-variations

I am building a shop online (with Woocommerce) that will display single and variable products. When in the single products page, I need some output/text to depend upon the selected product in the single product page being in or out of stock. I am building this conditioning in PHP.

For single products this is trivial:

```
$qty = $product->get_stock_quantity();
if ( ( ... ) and ( $qty > 0 ) ) {
    ...
}
```

I am hooking in `'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button'`.

However, for variable products I just don't know how to make it work. In this case, I need to get the selected/active variation quantity and this has to cope with the possibility of the client changing the variation in the page.

This question has been raised before BUT mostly for all variations and not the current/active one.

I would be grateful if someone could shed some light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to get the selected variation stock quantity is using jQuery/Javascript as it's mostly a live event on client side (not server side).

Your question is not really clear related to what you want to do, so here is a custom function function hooked in `woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button` action hook that target only variable products.

In that function I pass some data from php to javascript like:

- A custom message to be displayed for out of stock variations *(it could be also for "In stock")*
- All the active variations stock quantity.

The jQuery code detect:

- Which variation is selected (the variation ID),
- The stock status of the active selected variation

From there, this code is able to:

- Get the stock quantity fo the selected variation *(I don't know what you want to do with it)*
- Display a custom message when the selected variation is out of stock.

*In the jQuery code there is a function that will return the stock quantity for the selected variation.*

Here is this code example:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_button', 'get_selected_variation_stock', 11, 0 );
function get_selected_variation_stock() {
    global $product, $wpdb;

    // HERE set your custom message
    $message_outofstock = __('My custom "out of stock" message');

    // Get the visible product variations stock quantity
    $variations_data = array();
    $child_ids = $product->get_visible_children();
    $child_ids = implode( ',',$child_ids );
    $results = $wpdb->get_results( "
        SELECT p.ID, pm.meta_value as stock_qty
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts as p
        INNER JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta as pm ON p.ID = pm.post_id
        WHERE p.post_type LIKE 'product_variation'
        AND p.ID IN ($child_ids) AND pm.meta_key LIKE '_stock'
    " );

    foreach( $results as $result ){
        // Set in an indexed array for each variation ID the corresponding stock qty
        $variations_data[$result->ID] = $result->stock_qty;
    }

    ?>
    <script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        var vData = <?php echo json_encode($variations_data); ?>,
            stock = '.woocommerce-variation-availability > .stock';

        // Function that get the selected variation stock quantity and returns it
        function getTheStockQty( a=vData ){
            $.each( a, function( index, value ){
                if( index == $('input.variation_id').val() )
                    return value;
            });
        }

        // Once loaded (if a variation is selected by default)
        setTimeout(function(){
            var stockQty = getTheStockQty();
            if( 0 < $('input.variation_id').val() && $(stock).hasClass('out-of-stock')){ // OUT OF STOCK
                // Output a custom message for "out of stock"
                $(stock).text('<?php echo $message_outofstock; ?>');
                // Testing output in the browser JS console
                console.log('(1)'+$(stock).html()+' | Stock qty: '+stockQty);
            } else if( 0 < $('input.variation_id').val() ) { // IN STOCK
                // Testing output in the browser JS console
                console.log('(2)'+$(stock).html()+' | Stock qty: '+stockQty);
            }
        }, 300);

        // On live selected variation
        $('select').blur( function(){
            var stockQty = getTheStockQty();
            if( 0 < $('input.variation_id').val() && $(stock).hasClass('out-of-stock')){ // OUT OF STOCK
                // Output a custom message for "out of stock"
                $(stock).text('<?php echo $message_outofstock; ?>');
                // Testing output in the browser JS console
                console.log('(1 live)'+$(stock).html()+' | Stock qty: '+stockQty);
            } else if( 0 < $('input.variation_id').val() ) { // IN STOCK
                // Testing output in the browser JS console
                console.log('(2 live)'+$(stock).html()+' | Stock qty: '+stockQty);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php
}
```

*This code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.*

Tested and works

> With this code, you get all the necessary base code to customize things just like you want.

Comment: I used your code and adapted it successfully. However, when I enter the product page it now shows a kind of flickering. As if the product image and some content shrinked and then displayed correctly.